# What happens to a do..end block when passed to the new method?

Tags: ruby

I have two examples:

first:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :some_var
  def initialize
    @some_var = 42
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

p some_instance = SomeClass.new
another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end

p another_instance
```

result:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007fcdda047270 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fcdda047130 @some_var="foobar">
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

second:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :some_var
  def initialize
    @some_var = 42
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

p some_instance = SomeClass.new
p another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end

p another_instance
```

result:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007fdd3f0131e0 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fdd3f0130a0 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fdd3f0130a0 @some_var=42>
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I was expecting to get:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007fdd3f0131e0 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fcdda047130 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fcdda047130 @some_var="foobar">
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I understand that the assignment is more greedy than the `do...end` block. And that curlies are more greedy than the assignment as shown below:

third:

```
p yet_another_instance = SomeClass.new { |s| s.some_var = "foobar" }
p yet_another_instance
```

result:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007f9a420529c0 @some_var="foobar">
#<SomeClass:0x007f9a420529c0 @some_var="foobar">
```

But what happens to the `do...end` block in the second example? Does it just not get run?

Edit:

Taking @max_pleaner's suggestion :) seems like Ruby just ignores it completely:

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :some_var
  def initialize
    @some_var = 42
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

p some_instance = SomeClass.new
p another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  puts "cats and dogs?"
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end

p another_instance
```

result:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007fd01f96f130 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fd01f96eff0 @some_var=42>
#<SomeClass:0x007fd01f96eff0 @some_var=42>
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

So now I'm curious, under what conditions is a block completely ignored by Ruby? Is there any documentation about this happening?

Edit:

See accepted answer

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :some_var
  def initialize
    @some_var = 42
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

p some_instance = SomeClass.new
p (another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  puts "cats and dogs?"
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end)

p another_instance
```

result:

```
#<SomeClass:0x007fcc6a043060 @some_var=42>
cats and dogs?
#<SomeClass:0x007fcc6a042f20 @some_var="foobar">
#<SomeClass:0x007fcc6a042f20 @some_var="foobar">
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion arises because of difference precedence of `{ ... }` and `begin ... end` and you don't use parentheses to make it explicit. The expression

```
p another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  puts "cats and dogs?"
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end
```

Is interpreted as

```
p(another_instance = SomeClass.new) do |s|
  puts "cats and dogs?"
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end
```

so the block is passed to `#p`, not `SomeClass#new`. You can enforce the other order explicitly:

```
p(another_instance = SomeClass.new do |s|
  puts "cats and dogs?"
  s.some_var = "foobar"
end)
```

and this *will* execute the block in the way you expected.

Comment: Exactly. It sometimes happen I try to find bugs with `p` in my code, and I just add some more!